# Pass a property as parameter in VB.Net. Correctness of this behaviour

Tags: vb.net

If I have an object with a property:

```vb
Public Class TestClass

    Public Property Prop1 As Integer
    Public Property Prop2 As Integer

    Public Sub New(PropValue As Integer)
        Prop1 = PropValue
        Prop2 = PropValue * 2
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I pass that property as parameter in a function in this way:

```
Public Function TestFunctors(Obj As TestClass, PropertyFunc As Func(Of TestClass, Integer)) As Integer
    Return PropertyFunc(Obj)
End Function
```

The tests I made:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim testObject = New TestClass(4)

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Must return 4: {0}, Must return 8: {1}", TestFunctors(testObject, Function() testObject.Prop1), TestFunctors(testObject, Function() testObject.Prop2)))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Must return 77: {0}", TestFunctors(testObject, Function() 77)))

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

Everything works, but I'd like to know if my second test is consistent. Ingenually, I though that it mean: `Obj.Prop1`, `Obj.Prop2`, but when the function passed is a constant, why `Obj.77` doesn't throw? Am I sure that this behavior will be always the same? Is there any case in which it won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the case.

Check this:

```
Module StartupModule

    Sub Main()

        Dim testObject = New TestClass(4)

        Dim p1 As Func(Of TestClass, Integer) = Function(item)
                                                    Return item.Prop1
                                                End Function

        Dim p2 As Func(Of TestClass, Integer) = Function(item)
                                                    Return item.Prop2
                                                End Function

        Dim p3 As Func(Of TestClass, Integer) = Function(item)
                                                    Return 77
                                                End Function
        ' mind this
        Dim p4 As Func(Of TestClass, Integer) = Function() 77

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Must return 4: {0}, Must return 8: {1}", TestFunctors(testObject, p1), TestFunctors(testObject, p2)))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Must return 77: {0}", TestFunctors(testObject, p4)))


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function TestFunctors(Obj As TestClass, PropertyFunc As Func(Of TestClass, Integer)) As Integer
        Return PropertyFunc(Obj)
    End Function


    Public Class TestClass

        Public Property Prop1 As Integer
        Public Property Prop2 As Integer

        Public Sub New(PropValue As Integer)
            Prop1 = PropValue
            Prop2 = PropValue * 2
        End Sub

    End Class


End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things by using anonymous functions to return a property.  Just refer to the property.

```
Dim testObject = New TestClass(4)
Console.WriteLine(testObject.Prop1, testObject.Prop2)
```